# App does not listen indefinitely on a database connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a Facebook messenger chatbot and I am trying to do so using a Web application written in C#. (MVC)

So far so good, I have managed to make the chatbot answer with the same thing, but now I need to connect to a database, using the same application.

To be more precise, the same application is supposed to read and write from and to a database, in order to make the chatbot respond with "intelligent" answers. I have a controller for responding to clients and it does so, but I cannot seem to figure out how to connect to a database and feed the information that was read to the controller that needs to respond.

I have done some research and I know I am supposed to make a Startup.cs (currently I don't have one), and I presume that that is where I am supposed to read and write from the database, using workers, and get the information into the controller from there.

I do not want people to make my work for me, I just need guidance. I am having a really hard time with C# as my main focus is machine learning and python, but I can manage if given some guidance.

One of my ideas (which I haven't tried yet) was to make another controller (or 2? read-write) and try and call them in the other controller, for the chat?

Comment: Probably [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) is the right tool for this.

Comment: " I know I am supposed to make a Startup.cs"...no, this is irrelevant to making a database connection. You can find tutorials showing how to use either Entity Framework or ADO.NET to connect to a database.You can input and output values fairly easily either of using those libraries. It would also help us a little if you showed your existing controller code. Uwe is right though, SignalR (which uses a websockets) is probably a better choice for a chap app than regular MVC controllers. You can still save stuff to a database from there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a broader scope than it seems.

1. For client side, as Uwe Kim rightly said, for chat bot to maintain it's connection with server continuously, SignalR seems to be good option under the microsoft stack of technologies.
2. For server side solution, I would recommend having a look at micro services architecture (Set of loosely coupled services with it's own database) Identify informational categories & create microservices to handle those separately

A) Have a PrimaryController which will greet user with basic structured messages and categorize the request based on inputs received from user.Once it has identified the category, any special request which requires processing(like fetching data from database) will be passed to respective secondary async controller. Primary controller will await the response from secondary controller. If secondary controller replies with some more information, post the same to the client. Also the job of primary controller will be to validate the input which it can. Any other sanitization that needs database check may be passed on to respective secondary controllers.

B) The job of the secondary controller will be -
 1. Validate the inputs.
 2. Decide which all microservices to be involved for obtaining the necessary information
 3. Invoke the microservices as required
 4. Pass on the response received from microservices back to client via primary controller

These are just suggestion, you may think on similar lines ! Thanks